# IE11 form submit event is called, but the form is not submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, ecmascript-6

I'm having a weird problem that happens only on IE11. I have the following form:

```
<form id="myform" action="http://my.url.com/mypage" method="POST">
    <a href="#" class="js-triggerFileInput">Send the file</a>
    <input type="file" name="myfile" class="hidden js-inputFile" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="hidden" />
</form>
```

And the following javascript (ES6 with a transpiler):

```
class MyForm {
  constructor() {
    this.button = $('.js-triggerFileInput');
    this.file = $('.js-inputFile');
    this.form = $('#myform');
  }

  // when I click on the visible button, triggers the file input dialog box
  this.button.click(() => {
    this.file.click();
  });

  // the the file is selected in the dialog box, submit the form
  this.file.change(() => {
    this.form.submit();
  });

  // I added this just to debug
  this.form.submit(() => {
    console.log('submitted');
    return true;
  });
}
```

This work on all browsers, except IE11, the form is not submitted at all.

I added a debug to see if the submit event is called, and is called every time, but the browser don't submit the form.

If I try to submit the form using the submit button, it works fine, but when I try to submit using javascript, it triggers the event but doesn't work.

Does anyone know that is wrong with my code?

I even tried a different approach:

```
<label for="myinput">Send the file</label>
<input id="myinput" type="file" class="hidden" />
```

And use the default label/input behavior to trigger the input file without having to use `.click()` and it seems to work better, but in IE11 this doesn't work if the input file is hidden is invible (display: none, visibility: hidden or opacity: 0).

**Edit1**: if I trigger the event through the browser console, the form is submitted.

Comment: IE11 does not support arrow functions

Comment: @Taplar: OP is using transpiler, try again.

Comment: Any error messages in the console?

Comment: Nope, no errors in the console, not before or after the event is triggered.

Comment: Interesting, in that case the linked dup doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found the source of the problem, but I found a way to bypass this IE bug:

HTML:

```
<form id="myform" action="http://my.url.com/mypage" method="POST">
    <label for="myfile">Send the file</label>
    <input type="file" name="myfile" id="myfile" class="js-inputFile" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="hidden" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
class MyForm {
  constructor() {
    this.file = $('.js-inputFile');
    this.form = $('#myform');
  }

  // the the file is selected in the dialog box, submit the form
  this.file.change(() => {
    this.form.submit();
  });
}
```

If I don't use a button + JS to trigger the input[type="file"] behavior, and instead use label + id to trigger the click, it works like a charm. The problem seems to be related to triggering the input[type="file"] using JS.

Also:

- IE doesn't send the form if there isn't a input[type="submit"] inside the form.
- IE doesn't trigger the input[type="file"] is is hidden or invisible, I've achieved the same behavior using height: 0; width: 0;

Comment: The problems in the list are rather something IE7 - IE8 had at their time, are you sure you're running the page in the latest standards mode?